# What could be causing a Bosch dishwasher to not heat the water?

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Bosch SHX46a05UC/43 that is not heating the water inside. My first clue something was wrong was that the cycle time was very long (3-4 hours). I'm not sure that it can't heat the water, but in my exploring I've yet to find any hot water inside, regardless of which part of the cycle it's in when I check it.

Any suggestions on what to check next to determine the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most dishwashers, there's really only 2 or 3 parts that can cause this problem.

First is the heating coil itself. Disconnect it from whatever it's wired to. Measure the resistance of the coil with a multimeter. If it reads infinite **OR** 0, then the coil is bad. Anything in between and it's probably fine.

Next is the relay or the control board. On many dishwashers, the relay is on the control board. If yours is combined, then just buy a new control board. If the relay is separate, buy a relay because they are cheap. And if that doesn't fix the problem then it's the control board.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was a blown relay connection on the control board. I re-soldered the blow connection and the heater was working again.