# Where is the temperature sensor in a Bosch dishwasher?

Tags: dishwasher

My Bosch SMS65E12GB (Exxcel AquaStar 6.5L) dishwasher is running normally except that the dishes come out cold and not entirely clean. No error codes are showing and the cycles take the usual length of time. The diagnostic programme also came up with no errors.

Given that the cycles take the usual time I don't think this is the heating element or relay as in [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/39263/what-could-be-causing-a-bosch-dishwasher-to-not-heat-the-water) (if those go then the dishwasher will just wait a very long time for the water to heat up).

My guess is that there is a temperature sensor which is faulty (reading high) and is causing the heating element to cut off too soon. But I cannot find any mention of such a sensor either on Bosch's website or on 3rd party spares sites. I can find the water flow, turbidity, salt level and rinse aid level sensors but not a temperature sensor.

Do these dishwashers have a temperature sensor? Is it likely to be my problem? If so any idea of where it is/part number would be most helpful.

Comment: Have you checked the usual suspect, such as clean jets and pipes? Have you checked the filter?

Comment: Did suggest a temperature sensor would exist, but this must be a duplicate question.